# Android:Random Crash At illegal state Exception adapter has changed but listview doesnot receive notification

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter, illegalstateexception

Even I have called adapter and adapter.notifydatasetchnaged in UI thread only still it is crashing with following errors....

> this is my code snippet
>
> ```
> runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
>   public void run() {
>       _adapter = new HotspotListAdapter(_context, _productList,
>       _keyword,mImageInfoPopupDismissListener);
>       setListAdapter(_adapter);
>           }
>       });
> ```

when list view is scrolling then click list view data then app is  crashing.Any one have any idea to solve this problem

```
11-01 06:48:07.629: E/MessageQueue-JNI(29237):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1920)
    11-01 06:48:07.629: E/MessageQueue-JNI(29237):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2177)
    11-01 06:48:07.629: E/MessageQueue-JNI(29237):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1920)
    11-01 06:48:07.629: E/MessageQueue-JNI(29237):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2177)
    11-01 06:48:07.629: E/MessageQueue-JNI(29237):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1920)
    11-01 06:48:07.629: E/MessageQueue-JNI(29237):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2177)
    11-01 06:48:07.629: E/MessageQueue-JNI(29237):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1920)
    11-01 06:48:07.629: E/MessageQueue-JNI(29237):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2177)
    11-01 06:48:07.629: E/MessageQueue-JNI(29237):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1920)
    11-01 06:48:07.629: E/MessageQueue-JNI(29237):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1998)
    11-01 06:48:07.629: E/MessageQueue-JNI(29237):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1450)
    11-01 06:48:07.629: E/MessageQueue-JNI(29237):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2443)
    11-01 06:48:07.629: E/MessageQueue-JNI(29237):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1946)
    11-01 06:48:07.629: E/MessageQueue-JNI(29237):  at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7437)
    11-01 06:48:07.629: E/MessageQueue-JNI(29237):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3331)
    11-01 06:48:07.629: E/MessageQueue-JNI(29237):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3238)
    11-01 06:48:07.629: E/MessageQueue-JNI(29237):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:4403)
    11-01 06:48:07.629: E/MessageQueue-JNI(29237):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4382)
    11-01 06:48:07.629: E/MessageQueue-JNI(29237):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4474)
    11-01 06:48:07.629: E/MessageQueue-JNI(29237):  at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:179)
    11-01 06:48:07.629: E/MessageQueue-JNI(29237):  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
    11-01 06:48:07.629: E/MessageQueue-JNI(29237):  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:125)
    11-01 06:48:07.629: E/MessageQueue-JNI(29237):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:124)
    11-01 06:48:07.629: E/MessageQueue-JNI(29237):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5110)
    11-01 06:48:07.629: E/MessageQueue-JNI(29237):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    11-01 06:48:07.629: E/MessageQueue-JNI(29237):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    11-01 06:48:07.629: E/MessageQueue-JNI(29237):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:954)
    11-01 06:48:07.629: E/MessageQueue-JNI(29237):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:721)
    11-01 06:48:07.629: E/MessageQueue-JNI(29237):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem.
i was updating the adapter data out of Main Ui Thread Although i had been calling notifydatasetchange for the adapter.
try to Update Data and call notify datasetchange After that both in the main UI thread.
i wish it fix your problem